# Can not show API response message in C# Code

Tags: c#, json

I am going to generate Eway Bill API from below Request.The response of below request is showing fine in "Postmen" but at the same time when I execute this below request from C# Code then its shows an error message as **"The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."**.

I would like to know how to show the postmen error message in C# Code.

URL :-

```
https://ewbbackend-preprodpub-http.internal.cleartax.co/gst/v0.1/taxable_entities/1c74ddd2-6383-4f4b-a7a5-007ddd08f9ea/ewaybill/GLD23985?activity_type=GENERATE_EWB
```

Header :-

```
Content-type : application/json
X-Cleartax-Auth-Token : b1f57327-96db-4829-97cf-2f3a59a3a548
taxable_entity_id : b1f57327-96db-4829-97cf-2f3a59a3a548
```

Body :-

```
{
  "id": "GLD23985",
  "transaction_date": "26/10/2020",
  "source": "USER",
  "document_number": "BQ/20/0251",
  "type": "OUTWARD",
  "transport_mode": "ROAD",
  "dispatch_from_state": "HARYANA",
  "sub_supply": "Supply",
  "distance": "90",
  "vehicle_number": "TN32N1049",
  "document_type": "Tax Invoice",
  "seller": {
    "address1": "142/1,Trunk Road",
    "address2": "Perumugai",
    "city": "Via Vellore",
    "gstin": "29AEKPV7203E1Z9",
    "name": "K.H Exports India Private Limited",
    "state": "HARYANA",
    "zip_code": ""
  },
  "receiver": {
    "address1": "4/74, VOC Street, Seenerkuppam Village, ",
    "address2": "Poonamalle, Chennai 600 056",
    "city": "",
    "gstin": "33AAACR1714R1ZA",
    "name": "KH EXPORTS INDIA PVT.LTD. (LGD)",
    "state": "TAMIL NADU",
    "zip_code": "600003"
  },
  "consignee": {
    "city": "",
    "state": "TAMIL NADU",
    "zip_code": "600003"
  },
  "line_items": [
    {
      "cess_rate": "0",
      "cess_val": "0",
      "cgst_rate": "0",
      "cgst_val": "0",
      "description": "STYLE;91311 COLOUR;SVFD7 BELT & PA",
      "gst_code": "4203",
      "igst_rate": "28.00",
      "igst_val": "16800.000000",
      "item_code": "STYLE;91311 COLOUR;SVFD7 BELT & PA",
      "quantity": "3.00",
      "serial_number": "1",
      "sgst_rate": "0",
      "sgst_val": "0",
      "taxable_val": "600.0000",
      "unit_of_measurement": "NUMBERS"
    },
    {
      "cess_rate": "0",
      "cess_val": "0",
      "cgst_rate": "0",
      "cgst_val": "0",
      "description": "STYLE;91307 COLOUR;ABFD2 BELT & PA",
      "gst_code": "4203",
      "igst_rate": "28.00",
      "igst_val": "16800.000000",
      "item_code": "STYLE;91307 COLOUR;ABFD2 BELT & PA",
      "quantity": "3.00",
      "serial_number": "2",
      "sgst_rate": "0",
      "sgst_val": "0",
      "taxable_val": "600.0000",
      "unit_of_measurement": "NUMBERS"
    }
  ]
}
```

Response:-

```
{
    "errors": {
        "err_1": {
            "code": "BAD_REQUEST_ATTR",
            "message": "Pincode should have 6 digits.",
            "error_group_code": 0,
            "error_id": 0,
            "severity": "ERROR"
        }
    },
    "error_sources": {
        "seller": {
            "zip_code": {
                "error_refs": [
                    "err_1"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

C# Code:-

```
 string DATA = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tr, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

                using (var client = new WebClient())
                {
                    client.Headers.Add("taxable_entities", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["taxable_entities"]);
                    client.Headers.Add("X-Cleartax-Auth-Token", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["auth-token"]);
                    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
                    string url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["host"] + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["taxable_entities"] + "/ewaybill/" + TblHeader.Rows[0]["id"].ToString() + "?activity_type=GENERATE_EWB";
                    string res = client.UploadString(url, "PUT", DATA);
}
```

Comment: do you receive data in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Hi my friend you can use this code to handle your respond and get your answer.
The previous examples return an HttpResponseMessage message from the controller action, but you can also use HttpResponseException to return an HttpError. This lets you return a strongly-typed model in the normal success case, while still returning HttpError if there is an error

```
    public Product GetProduct(int id)
{
    Product item = repository.Get(id);
    if (item == null)
    {
        var message = string.Format("Product with id = {0} not found", id);
        throw new HttpResponseException(
            Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, message));
    }
    else
    {
        return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply,actually I am taking api from government,just I am executing this api,so please advise how can I control this error in C# Code